# What are my choices when I want to convert DVD format to AVI under Linux?

Tags: linux, software-rec, conversion, video-encoding

What software is out there there to convert to AVI from DVD?

Comment: Don't use avi container, use MKV or OGM.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: why?

Comment: @Tshepang For one, you can actually replicate the DVDs functionality 1:1 with MKV and OGM containers (that's not possible with avi).

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: someone said [you can't do menus](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5464/how-to-re-encode-a-dvd-into-a-single-file/5476#5476).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've become a very avid fan of [handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) - which comes in windows and linux flavors, with or without GUI - mostly because when I rip DVDs it's generally to load the movies onto my iPad, and handbrake comes with a set of presets for exactly that purpose, but it supports pretty much every format known to it or the underlying transcode layer.

Comment: Seconding the handbrake recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [OGMRip](http://ogmrip.sourceforge.net/en/manual.html) for a very intuitive GUI utility.

I always got rips I was happy with when using OGMRip.

Comment: This one comes with builtin profiles, eg. ogg theora, avi etc.. good.

Comment: @fred - It's a really nice feature of this program. You can go with one of a variety of profiles or tinker around. I tended to use .mkv containers with x264/AAC inside. Seemed to work very well.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I love [Acidrip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/acidrip/).  It shows the final command that does the action - Nice to learn and to know what's going-on at the backend.

In case of Ubuntu, its available in the repo as well (not sure about fedora)
`apt-get install acidrip`

Comment: It looks good.. youtube has some how-to vids..eg. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QmwqEajaVt4